# Convert normal text into password in MVC without using type="password"

Tags: model-view-controller

the following is my code,

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.ConfirmPassword, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control input-sm", @autocomplete = "off", @style = "color: black; text - shadow: none;", @onfocus = "this.style.color='black'; this.style.textShadow='none';", @onkeypress = "this.style.color='transparent'; this.style.textShadow='1px 1px 4px #000';",@PasswordChar="*"} })
```

and my  model is
[DataType(DataType.Password)]

```
public string Password { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what is your rquirment exactly. By the way, you have to create a fake input element (with id mask) and make your main element hidden (with id password) like as the following:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("SaveUser", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Username)
    <input id="mask" value="" onkeypress="setpasschar()" type="password"/>
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Password, new {@type="hidden"})
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
}
```

Then write `setpasschar()` to assign the value of `mask` to `password`:

```
<script>
    function setpasschar()
    {
        document.getElementById("Password").value = document.getElementById("mask").value;
    }
</script>
```

Now, you can do your magic with the password element.

my view model:

```
public class UserViewModel
{
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

my action:

```
public ActionResult SaveUser(UserViewModel user)
{
    return View();
}
```

Comment: is there any property in css to convert normal text into password format without using type password in input tag,when i use type password the password saved in browser is showing when mouse focus come to password field.I hope you understand my problem.

Comment: @arjun You can create or select a font for the input as a css style that maps all character to star or something like that.